# How do I calculate min and max from a user input in python3

Tags: python, max, min

```
def main():
    print("*** High School Diving ***")

    num_judges=int(input("How many judges are there? "))

    for i in range (num_judges):
            scores=int(input("Ender a score: " ))
    x=min(scores)
    y=max(scores)

    print("Min: ", x)
    print("Max: ", y)

main()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to take the `min` and `max` of? Your `scores` is just a single `int`.

Comment: @HaiVu: Homework is allowed on SO (and no longer tagged as homework). As long as it's a real question, whose answer could be useful to future searches, there's no problem.

Comment: And the user is gone...

Comment: Well, we can take the `max` of a list of no users more easily than of a single user, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a list, and append each entered score to it:

```
scores = []
for i in range (num_judges):
    scores.append(int(input("Enter a score: " )))
```

`max()` and `min()` will then pick the highest and lowest value respectively from that list.

What you did, instead, was *replacing* `scores` with a new value each time you looped; then try and find the `min()` of one integer, which doesn't work:

```
>>> min(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

By using a list, the `min()` function can loop over it (iterate) and find your minimum value:

```
>>> min([1, 2, 3])
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more ways you could do this.

First, at least two people have already posted the exact same thing as the first answer by Martijn Pieters's answer, and I don't want to feel left out, so:

```
scores = []
for i in range(num_judges):
    scores.append(int(input("Enter a score: ")))
x=min(scores)
y=max(scores)
```

---

Now, whenever you create an empty list and append to it in a loop, this is identical to a list comprehension, so:

```
scores = [int(input("Enter a score: ")) for i in range(num_judges)]
x=min(scores)
y=max(scores)
```

---

Meanwhile, what if `num_judges` is huge, and you don't want to build that huge list just to find the min and max values? Well, you could keep track of them as you go along:

```
x, y = float('inf'), float('-inf')
for i in range(num_judges):
    score = int(input("Enter a score: "))
    if score < x:
        x = score
    if score > y:
        y = score
```

---

Finally, is there a way to get the best of both worlds? Usually, this just means using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. But here, you need both `min` and `max` to traverse the scores, which means it has to be a list (or something else reusable).

You can get around this with `tee`:

```
scores= (int(input("Enter a score: ")) for i in range(num_judges))
scores1, scores2 = itertools.tee(scores)
x = min(scores1)
y = max(scores2)
```

However, this doesn't really help, because under the covers, `tee` is going to create the same list you would have already created. (`tee` is very useful when you're going to traverse two iterators in parallel, but not in cases like this.)

So, you need to write a `min_and_max` function, which is going to look a lot like the `for` loop in the previous example:

```
def min_and_max(iter):
    x, y = float('inf'), float('-inf')
    for val in iter:
        if val < x:
            x = val
        if val > y:
            y = val
    return x, y
```

And then, you can do the whole thing in a nice, readable one-liner:

```
x, y = min_and_max(int(input("Enter a score: ")) for i in range(num_judges))
```

Of course it's not really a one-liner when you had to write an 8-line function to make it work… except that 8-line function may be reusable in other problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a variable `scores` inside the for loop, which won't be visible outside it. Secondly, you are trying to over-writing the value in `scores` on each iteration, since `scores` is not a `list` rather a `scalar` type.

You should declare `scores` as `list` type outside the loop, and inside the loop, `append` each score to the list.

```
scores = []
for i in range (num_judges):
        scores.append(int(input("Ender a score: " )))
x=min(scores)
y=max(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, you just need to make `scores` a list and append to it, then this should work:

```
def main():
    print("*** High School Diving ***")

    num_judges=int(input("How many judges are there? "))

    #define scores as a list of values
    scores = []
    for i in range (num_judges):
            scores.append(int(input("Ender a score: " ))) #append each value to scores[]
    x=min(scores)
    y=max(scores)

    print("Min: ", x)
    print("Max: ", y)

main()
```

If you take a look at the documentation for [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) they actually give you the syntax there an note that it requires an iterable type (such as a non-empty string, tuple or list).